# How do I console log (debugg) what is inside my html file in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, debugging, console.log

Here is what I've tried in VS. However, it's not giving the output I want.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <h1 id="header"> Here is some text</h1>
        <p id="foot">PLACEHOLDER</p>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

```
    var header = document.getElementById("header")
    console.log(Object.keys(header.style))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.094 seconds
```

**The output should be:**

```
["alignContent", "alignItems", "alignSelf", "alignmentBaseline",.....]
```

Comment: Are you trying to display this information inside Visual Studio itself, or are the log messages not shown in your browser?

Comment: If your running this html in browser, then the output of console log will display in your browser devtools. You can use F12 to open devtools or right-click on the browser page and choose inspect. Alternatively, you can setup vscode to act as a debugger for your browser.